# Apache configuration AWS API Gateway certificates

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, pem, aws-api-gateway

I've created an AWS API Gateway and I'm pointing it at a VPS. I want to be able to enable Client-Side SSL Authentication to my VPS. I followed the AWS walkthrough [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html). I generated a PEM-encoded certificate in the API Gateway console and copied it to my Apache web server. It appears that the certificate and/or vhost configuration is causing a fatal error in the Apache SSL module.

The error log:

```
[Tue Nov 10 10:53:57.140815 2015] [ssl:info] [pid 7283] AH01914: Configuring server example.com:443 for SSL protocol
[Tue Nov 10 10:53:57.140998 2015] [ssl:trace1] [pid 7283] ssl_engine_init.c(724): Configuring permitted SSL ciphers [!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXP:HIGH:!aNULL]
[Tue Nov 10 10:53:57.141165 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 7283] ssl_engine_init.c(843): AH01904: Configuring server certificate chain (1 CA certificate)
[Tue Nov 10 10:53:57.141175 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 7283] ssl_engine_init.c(390): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Tue Nov 10 10:53:57.141204 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 7283] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for example.com:443
[Tue Nov 10 10:53:57.141226 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 7283] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Tue Nov 10 10:53:57.141251 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 7283] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Apache vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example

    DirectoryIndex index.html

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateChainFile ssl/ca.crt
    SSLVerifyDepth 1

    LogLevel info ssl:warn debug trace1

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You can't require/use SSL client certificates unless you also have an SSL *server* certificate.  I don't see that cert and its private key configured, here, and `Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for example.com:443` seems to suggest that this is the problem.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes you are absolutely correct. I have created a self-signed certificate added, the key and cert into the Apache config and the server is starting up correctly. Now API Gateway is complaining about an 'Unknown endpoint error."

Comment: API gateway is unlikely to negotiate with a back-end server using a self-signed certificate.  It needs to authenticate the endpoint, which a self-signed cert doesn't allow... the cert has to be from an accredited Certificate Authority in order for the authentication to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Further research has proved @Michael - sqlbot was correct on both counts. A certificate from a Certificate Authority is required before AWS API Gateway will communicate with a 3rd party server endpoint.

Comment: I know it has been a while, but would you be able to update what your vhost configuration looks like now that you got this working and explain a bit about it?